# Path of db.worker.js file cannot be resolved after upgrade to NativeScript 6

Tags: angular, path, nativescript, upgrade, worker

I have a `src/app/sqlite/db.ts` file which handles access to a database.
It uses `src/app/util/Utils.ts` to create a pool of Workers, for background processing (`db.worker.js`).

The Utils file instantiates a new worker, which worked on tns 5, but not on tns 6:

- https://gitlab.com/thiagoufg/BudgetSMS/blob/master/src/app/util/Utils.ts#L186

As soon as the app starts on android emulator, it will give you an error stating that it cannot load the `db.worker.js file`.

My last 2 commits are on tns 6.

The commit bellow was still on tns 5 and things were working:

- https://gitlab.com/thiagoufg/BudgetSMS/commit/881854fa619b16e21fe64db0bb4ff6d9a80d82a4

Can anybody help me successfully load the `db.worker.js` module?

This is a personal project which I'm sharing with you guys. I wasn't planning to share it, but it's been really difficult to upgrade nativescript to newer versions. I basically have to create a new blank project and copy my stuff from the old version to the new, because the upgrade instructions never work for me. So I've decided to share it so that you may see whatever files you need to see.

This app violates Googles rules (by reading SMS messages), so it cannot be published on Play Store.

I've tried changing the workerPath inside db.ts to:

- ./db.worker.js
- ~/app/sqlite/worker.js
- and many other variations

I've tried messing with webpack.config.js, adding ts-loader, removing ts-loader, messing with the CopyWebpackPlugin, adding globs, etc, using NativeScriptWorkerPlugin, etc

https://gitlab.com/thiagoufg/BudgetSMS/blob/master/src/app/util/Utils.ts#L186

```
const MyWorker = require(`nativescript-worker-loader!${workerPath}`);
```

Expected result: no errors, access to the sqlite database as soon as the app loads.

Error I'm getting: as soon as the app loads:

> `Cannot find module 'nativescript-worker-loader!./db.worker.js'`

Comment: Have you updated your webpack config to latest? Then most probably const `MyWorker = require('nativescript-worker-loader!${workerPath}');` should work. Since you mentioned you are willing to share the project, can you make the repo public. The links are not accessible now.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had made it public... Try now again, please... And well, I think I have the newest files, because i have created a new tns 6 project from scratch, and migrated stuff from the old version to the new... I have not replaced newer versions of critical files with the older... I've tried to edit them carefully, instead...

Comment: The worker file seems not present in [latest code](https://gitlab.com/thiagoufg/BudgetSMS/tree/master/src/app/sqlite)?

Comment: Ouch... Js files are in .gitignore of new projects (because it generates js from ts)... I've now force added all the .js worker files

Comment: But the files were present on my machine... just not on gitlab... the error still happens and the question remains! Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: Looks like you are loading the worker file actually form utils, but it's present in sqlite folder. Try using `../sqlite/db.worker.js`?

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that before, but I did it again now... Error still happens: "Cannot find module 'nativescript-worker-loader!../sqlite/db.worker.js'"

Comment: Your `webpack.config.js` seems not matching the [latest template](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/blob/master/templates/webpack.angular.js).

Comment: Hey, @Manoj, I have eye checked my file and the template and they seem pretty similar to me... I've make a few tweaks in an attempt to fix the problem, but they're essentially identical... I have even compared that template and my file with a diff tool and they have very few differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update `webpack.config.js` to latest

   ./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs --deps

**Note:** You didn't need `ts-loader` as you are using JS file by default, also `new NativeScriptWorkerPlugin({ plugins: [ngCompilerPlugin] })` was not required.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const { join, relative, resolve, sep, dirname } = require("path");

const webpack = require("webpack");
const nsWebpack = require("nativescript-dev-webpack");
const nativescriptTarget = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/nativescript-target");
const { nsReplaceBootstrap } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-replace-bootstrap");
const { nsReplaceLazyLoader } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-replace-lazy-loader");
const { nsSupportHmrNg } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-support-hmr-ng");
const { getMainModulePath } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/utils/ast-utils");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer");
const { NativeScriptWorkerPlugin } = require("nativescript-worker-loader/NativeScriptWorkerPlugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const { getAngularCompilerPlugin } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/plugins/NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin");
const hashSalt = Date.now().toString();

module.exports = env => {
    // Add your custom Activities, Services and other Android app components here.
    const appComponents = [
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame",
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity",
    ];

    const platform = env && (env.android && "android" || env.ios && "ios");
    if (!platform) {
        throw new Error("You need to provide a target platform!");
    }

    const AngularCompilerPlugin = getAngularCompilerPlugin(platform);
    const projectRoot = __dirname;

    // Default destination inside platforms/<platform>/...
    const dist = resolve(projectRoot, nsWebpack.getAppPath(platform, projectRoot));

    const {
        // The 'appPath' and 'appResourcesPath' values are fetched from
        // the nsconfig.json configuration file.
        appPath = "src",
        appResourcesPath = "App_Resources",

        // You can provide the following flags when running 'tns run android|ios'
        aot, // --env.aot
        snapshot, // --env.snapshot,
        production, // --env.production
        uglify, // --env.uglify
        report, // --env.report
        sourceMap, // --env.sourceMap
        hiddenSourceMap, // --env.hiddenSourceMap
        hmr, // --env.hmr,
        unitTesting, // --env.unitTesting
        verbose, // --env.verbose
    } = env;

    const isAnySourceMapEnabled = !!sourceMap || !!hiddenSourceMap;
    const externals = nsWebpack.getConvertedExternals(env.externals);
    const appFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appPath);
    const appResourcesFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appResourcesPath);
    const tsConfigName = "tsconfig.tns.json";
    const entryModule = `${nsWebpack.getEntryModule(appFullPath, platform)}.ts`;
    const entryPath = `.${sep}${entryModule}`;
    const entries = { bundle: entryPath };
    const areCoreModulesExternal = Array.isArray(env.externals) && env.externals.some(e => e.indexOf("tns-core-modules") > -1);
    if (platform === "ios" && !areCoreModulesExternal) {
        entries["tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules"] = "inspector_modules";
    };

    const ngCompilerTransformers = [];
    const additionalLazyModuleResources = [];
    if (aot) {
        ngCompilerTransformers.push(nsReplaceBootstrap);
    }

    if (hmr) {
        ngCompilerTransformers.push(nsSupportHmrNg);
    }

    // when "@angular/core" is external, it's not included in the bundles. In this way, it will be used
    // directly from node_modules and the Angular modules loader won't be able to resolve the lazy routes
    // fixes https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4024
    if (env.externals && env.externals.indexOf("@angular/core") > -1) {
        const appModuleRelativePath = getMainModulePath(resolve(appFullPath, entryModule), tsConfigName);
        if (appModuleRelativePath) {
            const appModuleFolderPath = dirname(resolve(appFullPath, appModuleRelativePath));
            // include the lazy loader inside app module
            ngCompilerTransformers.push(nsReplaceLazyLoader);
            // include the new lazy loader path in the allowed ones
            additionalLazyModuleResources.push(appModuleFolderPath);
        }
    }

    const ngCompilerPlugin = new AngularCompilerPlugin({
        hostReplacementPaths: nsWebpack.getResolver([platform, "tns"]),
        platformTransformers: ngCompilerTransformers.map(t => t(() => ngCompilerPlugin, resolve(appFullPath, entryModule), projectRoot)),
        mainPath: join(appFullPath, entryModule),
        tsConfigPath: join(__dirname, tsConfigName),
        skipCodeGeneration: !aot,
        sourceMap: !!isAnySourceMapEnabled,
        additionalLazyModuleResources: additionalLazyModuleResources
    });

    let sourceMapFilename = nsWebpack.getSourceMapFilename(hiddenSourceMap, __dirname, dist);

    const itemsToClean = [`${dist}/**/*`];
    if (platform === "android") {
        itemsToClean.push(`${join(projectRoot, "platforms", "android", "app", "src", "main", "assets", "snapshots")}`);
        itemsToClean.push(`${join(projectRoot, "platforms", "android", "app", "build", "configurations", "nativescript-android-snapshot")}`);
    }

    nsWebpack.processAppComponents(appComponents, platform);
    const config = {
        mode: production ? "production" : "development",
        context: appFullPath,
        externals: {
            ...externals,
            'nativescript-sqlite-commercial': 'nativescript-sqlite-commercial',
            'nativescript-sqlite-encrypted': 'nativescript-sqlite-encrypted'
        },
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: [
                appResourcesFullPath,
                // Don't watch hidden files
                "**/.*",
            ]
        },
        target: nativescriptTarget,
        entry: entries,
        output: {
            pathinfo: false,
            path: dist,
            sourceMapFilename,
            libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
            filename: "[name].js",
            globalObject: "global",
            hashSalt
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".scss", ".css"],
            // Resolve {N} system modules from tns-core-modules
            modules: [
                resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/tns-core-modules"),
                resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                "node_modules/tns-core-modules",
                "node_modules",
            ],
            alias: {
                '~': appFullPath
            },
            symlinks: true
        },
        resolveLoader: {
            symlinks: false
        },
        node: {
            // Disable node shims that conflict with NativeScript
            "http": false,
            "timers": false,
            "setImmediate": false,
            "fs": "empty",
            "__dirname": false,
        },
        devtool: hiddenSourceMap ? "hidden-source-map" : (sourceMap ? "inline-source-map" : "none"),
        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: "single",
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        name: "vendor",
                        chunks: "all",
                        test: (module, chunks) => {
                            const moduleName = module.nameForCondition ? module.nameForCondition() : '';
                            return /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/.test(moduleName) ||
                                appComponents.some(comp => comp === moduleName);
                        },
                        enforce: true,
                    },
                }
            },
            minimize: !!uglify,
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    parallel: true,
                    cache: true,
                    sourceMap: isAnySourceMapEnabled,
                    terserOptions: {
                        output: {
                            comments: false,
                            semicolons: !isAnySourceMapEnabled
                        },
                        compress: {
                            // The Android SBG has problems parsing the output
                            // when these options are enabled
                            'collapse_vars': platform !== "android",
                            sequences: platform !== "android",
                        }
                    }
                })
            ],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    include: join(appFullPath, entryPath),
                    use: [
                        // Require all Android app components
                        platform === "android" && {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/android-app-components-loader",
                            options: { modules: appComponents }
                        },

                        {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/bundle-config-loader",
                            options: {
                                angular: true,
                                loadCss: !snapshot, // load the application css if in debug mode
                                unitTesting,
                                appFullPath,
                                projectRoot,
                                ignoredFiles: nsWebpack.getUserDefinedEntries(entries, platform)
                            }
                        },
                    ].filter(loader => !!loader)
                },

                { test: /\.html$|\.xml$/, use: "raw-loader" },

                // tns-core-modules reads the app.css and its imports using css-loader
                {
                    test: /[\/|\\]app\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader",
                        { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader",
                        { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } },
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                },

                // Angular components reference css files and their imports using raw-loader
                { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /[\/|\\]app\.css$/, use: "raw-loader" },
                { test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/, use: ["raw-loader", "resolve-url-loader", "sass-loader"] },

                {
                    test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/moduleid-compat-loader",
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/lazy-ngmodule-hot-loader",
                        "@ngtools/webpack",
                    ]
                },

                // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
                // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
                {
                    test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\]core[\/\\].+\.js$/,
                    parser: { system: true },
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            // Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                "process": "global.process",
            }),
            // Remove all files from the out dir.
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(itemsToClean, { verbose: !!verbose }),
            // Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.sqlite" } }
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
            new nsWebpack.GenerateNativeScriptEntryPointsPlugin("bundle"),
            // For instructions on how to set up workers with webpack
            // check out https://github.com/nativescript/worker-loader
            new NativeScriptWorkerPlugin(),
            ngCompilerPlugin,
            // Does IPC communication with the {N} CLI to notify events when running in watch mode.
            new nsWebpack.WatchStateLoggerPlugin(),
        ],
    };

    if (report) {
        // Generate report files for bundles content
        config.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: "static",
            openAnalyzer: false,
            generateStatsFile: true,
            reportFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `report.html`),
            statsFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `stats.json`),
        }));
    }

    if (snapshot) {
        config.plugins.push(new nsWebpack.NativeScriptSnapshotPlugin({
            chunk: "vendor",
            angular: true,
            requireModules: [
                "reflect-metadata",
                "@angular/platform-browser",
                "@angular/core",
                "@angular/common",
                "@angular/router",
                "nativescript-angular/platform-static",
                "nativescript-angular/router",
            ],
            projectRoot,
            webpackConfig: config,
        }));
    }

    if (hmr) {
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    }

    return config;
};
```

2. Your require statement was dynamic,

   const MyWorker = require(`nativescript-worker-loader!${workerPath}`);

Making it static solved the issue,

```
const MyWorker = require('nativescript-worker-loader!../sqlite/db.worker.js');
```

I'm sure there is an option to keep the require statement dynamic, but you would need an extra step, something like registering module. I will have to check the docs / code, update when I can. This should keep you going for now.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj ... your suggestions did work... If you find out how to use dynamic requires, please, let me know! Have a nice weekend!

Comment: @thiago see this thread about how to use dynamic imports with Webpack https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/issues/989#issuecomment-512205358